# spreading out vertices of networkx in k-partite graph

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have a k-partite graph in which the nodes are very close to each other. If I put the label option True it looks very cluttered.

1) How can I spread the graph with adequate distances among nodes
2) If node labels are big how to increase the size of nodes, so that it fits the labels within.

Following is the code snippet

```
 G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(emc["entity"], bipartite=0)
G.add_nodes_from(set(EMM_unique["keys"]).symmetric_difference(set(emc["entity"])), bipartite=1)
G.add_nodes_from(EMM["id"], bipartite=2)
G.add_edges_from(list(emc.itertuples(index=False)))
G.add_edges_from(list(EMM.itertuples(index=False)))

nodes = G.nodes()
# for each of the parts create a set
nodes_0  = set([n for n in nodes if  G.nodes[n]['bipartite']==0])
nodes_1  = set([n for n in nodes if  G.nodes[n]['bipartite']==1])
nodes_2  = set([n for n in nodes if  G.nodes[n]['bipartite']==2])


 # set the location of the nodes for each set
pos = dict()
pos.update( (n, (i, -1)) for i, n in enumerate(nodes_0) ) # put nodes from X at x=1
pos.update( (n, (i, -2)) for i, n in enumerate(nodes_1) ) # put nodes from Y at x=2
pos.update( (n, (i, -3)) for i, n in enumerate(nodes_2) ) # put nodes from X at x=1


color_map = []
for node in G:
    if node in emc["entity"].values:
       color_map.append("red")
    elif node in EMM["id"].values:
        color_map.append("green")
    else:
        color_map.append("cyan")

nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=color_map, node_size= [len(n)*20 for n in G.nodes()], font_color= "blue",font_size=7, alpha=0.7, node_shape="s", with_labels=True, with_arrows=True)
```

I have already tried the option of changing node_size by string node length, but as one can see from the image it is too cluttered due to less distance between the nodes. Can someone also help me to create a label box outside the nodes? That option will fix the issue as well. Thanks

PS I know such options are available in bipartite layout but I am not using bipartite.

[image]

Comment: As alternative to yatu's answer, is it allowed to modify your node positions? You could easily add a spreading factor for each of your three levels

Comment: yes the only thing is it should show not change the layout. But at its level, each node set can spread further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're fixing the positions, the issue really is that there isn't enough spacing for the labels to be readable, and they'll overlap. So if you want to keep these positions, one thing you could do is to *rotate* the labels. For that you can draw separately the labels with `nx.draw_networkx_labels` and then rotate them with:

```
nx.draw(G, pos, 
        node_color=color_map, 
        font_size=7, 
        with_labels=False,
        alpha=0.7, 
        node_shape="s", 
        with_arrows=True)

label = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, 
                               pos,
                               font_size=12)

for _,n in label .items():
    n.set_rotation('vertical')
```